# The function should return the string multiplied by the integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Define a function called multiply. It should have one required parameter, a string. It should also have one optional parameter, an integer, named mult_int, with a default value of 10. The function should return the string multiplied by the integer. (i.e.: Given inputs “Hello”, mult_int=3, the funct

```
mult_int=10
def multiply(x,mult_int):
    return str(x)*mult_int
```

Error: TypeError: multiply() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

[source:](https://www.programsinformationpeople.org/runestone/static/publicpy3/OptionalAndKeywordParameters/ExtraExercises.html)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Comment: How are you calling the function `multiply()`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To set a default value in a function you should do like in the code bellow and you don't have to use str to convert x to a string, just send the string.

```
def multiply(x,mult_int=10):
    return x*mult_int

print(multiply("I hope that's not your homework.\n", 2))
print(multiply("Bye."))
```

Comment: no,it's not my homework